# Trying Scale_color_manual with ampvis2 Boxplot without outcome

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to color my ampvis Boxplot with the Scale_color_manual command. There is no error but I can't see my Boxplots anymore. This whole R thing is new for me and kind of tricky.
Maybe you can help me.

My script is :

```
    amp_boxplot(Paperchaetocerosfinal1, group_by = "Kombination", sort_by = "median", plot_type = "boxplot",
            point_size = 1, tax_aggregate = "Species", tax_add = "Genus", tax_show = 20, 
            tax_empty = "best", tax_class = NULL, order_group = NULL, order_y = NULL,
            plot_flip = FALSE, plot_log = FALSE, adjust_zero = NULL, 
            normalise = TRUE, detailed_output = FALSE) +
scale_color_manual(aesthetics = "colour", values = c("OA_Strongly stratified scenario" = "red",
                              "OA_Present_day" = "black",
                              "OA_Deep_mixing_scenario" = "blue",
                              "Ambient_Strongly_stratified_scenario" = "grey",
                              "Ambient_Present_day" = "black",
                              "Ambient_Deep_mixing_scenario" = "blue"))
```

and my outcome is zero :D

Comment: Why don't you use `ggplot2` package for that purpose? it would be much more effective and easier.

Comment: I did not know, that I could use ggplot2 for OTU data. But then I will try! Thank you!